# iText PDF Table error using writeSelectedRows

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have the next error.
I'm trying to create a PDF using iText, with an specific format. I opted to use tables for each section of the page, because the format that I need to do have tables. All right, I already did everything, I create the tables and adding it with the `doc.add(table)` method, this worked fine, but I needed to set the tables into an specific position. So I opted to use `table.writeSelectedRows()` method, and this worked fine.

And here comes the error, this is my code:

```
table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_White);
                table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_White);
                table_SectionTwo.addCell(p);
                table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_OrderDate);   
                table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_CustomerOrderDate);
                table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_OrderNumberSection);                                                              

    float[] columnWidths = new float[] {38f, 105f, 90f};
                    table_SectionTwo.setTotalWidth(columnWidths);
                    table_SectionTwo.setLockedWidth(true);
                    table_SectionTwo.completeRow();                 
                    table_SectionTwo.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 260f, 770f, super.getPdfWriter().getDirectContent());                     
                    doc.add(table_SectionTwo);
```

As you can see, if I execute this code, this will add the same table 2 times

the problem is when I remove doc.add(table), I do this only for add one table into an specific position using `table.writeSelectedRows()`. This is how my code remains:

```
table_SectionTwo.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 260f, 770f, super.getPdfWriter().getDirectContent());                     
//super.addTable(table_SectionTwo);
```

I commented `doc.add(table)`.
And this should write only one table. But this doesn't work. When I do this throws:

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:113)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1217)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:777)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:398)
    at PDFConstructor.CloseDocument(PDFConstructor.java:85)
    at InvoicePDF.CloseDocument(InvoicePDF.java:58)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:72)
```

The curious thing is when I comment the  `doc.add(table)` this doesn't work, and when I comment the `table.writeSelectedRows()` the `doc.add(table)` works fine. 
This error occurs only when I have `doc.add(table)` commented and `table.writeSelectedRows()` uncommented.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't give sufficient information in your question, I think the problem is caused by the fact that you don't define the width of the table.

Do this test: ask the table for its total height. If iText returns 0, then you forgot to define the width of the table; if it doesn't return 0, then iText knows the width either because you defined it explicitly, or because you used document.add(table), which calculated the dimensions of the table based on the page metrics of the document object.

If something else is at play, you'll have to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question that you want to write specific rows to document but at a specified position.If this is correct super.getPdfWriter().getDirectContent()) is that necessary?i don't think so.To analyse this part i need your whole code snippet or a demo version of this code which explain the same.

2nd:Internally itext also use PdfContentByte to write PdfPTable using PdfPRow & also Remember according to the author(Bruno) itext is built on Builder Pattern.If previous lines have no meaning to you skip it.

You currently adding content to table even before its all required property is set.

```
table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_White);
table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_White);
table_SectionTwo.addCell(p);
table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_OrderDate);   
table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_CustomerOrderDate);
table_SectionTwo.addCell(cell_OrderNumberSection);
```

It will be something like this

```
float[] columnWidths = new float[] {38f, 105f, 90f};
PdfPTable table_SectionTwo= new PdfPTable(clmnWdthTpHdr);
table_SectionTwo.setTotalWidth(500.0f);
table_SectionTwo.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
table_SectionTwo.setLockedWidth(true);
```

3.Don't use super.getPdfWriter().getDirectContent()).As the above code shows me you are using document so i think you must write following code snippet too(Something like this:lol)

```
PdfWriter pdfWrtr=null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document doc= new Document(UtilConstant.pageSizePdf,0,0,0,0);
pdfWrtr=PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,baos);
```

In try catch use pdfWrtr.getDirectContent(); instead.
These all are based on my code analysis.
Also another point from the exception

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:113)
...............................
 at InvoicePDF.CloseDocument(InvoicePDF.java:58)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:72)
```

It is a typical error when nothing is added to the document.Maybe an exception is thrown (and ignored) in step 4(according to Itext in Action) andmaybe you are executing step 5 (document.close()) anyway(in spite of the exception in step 4).So please attach Demo.java
if the above is not clear enough to help you.